# Google charts not rendered in Safari only

Tags: javascript, drupal, safari

I have written a js for rendering graphs but it is not showing any graph on the Safari browser.

```
google.charts.load("currrent", {packages:["corechart"]});

var external_retrive = 
  Drupal.settings.external;
  var external = [["External ","Status"]];
  var external_wrapper = 'external';
  for (var value in external_retrive) {
    external_.push([external_retrive[value] 
    ['title'],parseInt(external_retrive[value]['value'])]);
  }
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawExternal);
  function drawExternal() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(external);
    var options = {
      title: 'External',
      pieHole: 0.4,
    };
    var chart = new 
      google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('external'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}
```

I have tried with changing the

```
google.charts.load("visualization", "1.1" , {packages:["corechart"]});
```

Tried enabling Adobe Flash in Safari.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Solved just called the function to draw the graph as third argument in the google.charts.load.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your solution and post here the solution?